# How best to frame this database query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm looking for a way to frame a query to the database. Here is the scenario.
I have 3 `tables`: `tags`, `sentenceTags` and `sentences`. `tags` has field of `id` and `name` which is the name of the tag. `sentenceTags` has `sentenceId`, `tagId` as foreign keys, and other fields like `createdAt`(not really important to my question).

Now, I get a search request via API to return sentences with a tag of say `books`. So I have to search `tags` table for an entry with name field equal `books` and return the `id`. Using this `id` I need to query the `sentenceTags` table and then the `sentences` table in that order.

I thought of using multiple `select` statements as I can't think of how to `join` the 3 tables. Or perhaps `union`. My question is: what is the better way of making such a query? I just need a clue or some tips on how to do this.

Comment: Create an SQL Fiddle please http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  Are you familiar with how databases work?

Comment: Alright let me try to do that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah I know the basics. But how to join the three tables. Since they all do not have common fields I can `join` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use join 2 times, your query will look like this :

```
select * from tags t join sentenceTags st on t.id=st.tagId join sentences s on st.sentenceId=s.id where t.name='books';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is about the simplest way of joining them:

```
SELECT * FROM tags, sentenceTags, sentences WHERE tags.name = 'books' AND tags.id = sentenceTags.tagId AND sentences.id = sentenceTags.sentenceId
```

Comment: Also the most old way to JOIN.. it could become deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `sentenceTag` table is an intermediate table connecting the both `tags` and `sentence`. You have the `sentenceId` is coming from `sentence` and `tagsId` from `tag` table.

You just need to select using JOIN from all tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    tags
JOIN
    sentenceTags
ON
    tags.id = sentenceTags.tagID
JOIN
    sentence
ON
    sentence.id = sentenceTags.sentenceId
WHERE
    tags.name = 'Books'
```